# is this possible with activex controls?

Tags: c#, c++, internet-explorer, activex

I'm developing an Activex controller for IE7.
I want to check version of flash+svg and install it if missing or old, and also change some settings in IE like setting up the printer to use landscape format..

I'm completly new to activex, so i'm trying to figure out how to do it, can you please post some pointers ? is what i'm trying to do possible with activex controls ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see what this question has to do with Java.

Comment: maybe there's an API out there to develop with java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Windows Vista, IE7 will run in Protected Mode (unless User Account Control is disabled) so the browser will run in a sandbox with very low rights. It prevents exactly what you're trying to do. You can override it only if you have full control of the target systems (i.e. using policies) but in this case you don't have to use this "trojan horse" method to deploy Flash...

Comment: I downloaded flash activex's .cab and found an executable file there.. is it just not possible to write a simple activex to just call those executable files (svg, flash ..) ? my activex will be a big packed .cab file

Comment: CAB files are the standard way to deploy ActiveX on IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974288.aspx

Comment: I mean, my_activex.cab will contain : (install_flash.exe - install_svg.exe - setup_printer.exe - install.exe - autorun.inf)  ..... autorun.inf will start install.exe which will call the other 3 exec files.. what do you think of this hint ?

Comment: I have never tried something like this... but in theory it could work. You will get an elevation prompt when installing the CAB, so executables launched by the inf installer should have enough privileges to being installed. However, you will get a bunch of warnings since your CAB will not be signed with Authenticode. You can try to self sign and install yourself as root CA if you are the administrator of the target machines.